# Do all of Grisaia's Mihama girls suffer from PTSD?

Tags: grisaia

The cast of heroines of the Grisaia no Kajitsu visual novel / anime series are some of the most deranged of the last decade.

Do all of them suffer from some sort of PTSD?

They surely have reasons to:

Amane:

> Surviving the bus crash, starvation, the death of classmates, the cannibal circle and the guilty for her best friend's sacrifice. Not to mention crawling for weeks eating bugs and leeches before reaching civilization.

Makina:

> Tied up in front of her dead father's decomposing body for days.

Michiru:

> Best friend committed suicide in front of her.

Sachi:

> Getting her parents killed by a runaway truck because she was a bad girl.

Yumiko:

> Rejected by family. Watching her mother mentally decay in front of her. Being treated as less than a person by her father.

Bonus: Chizuru:

> The kidnapping?

Answer (score 1):

The only one we know for sure is **Sachi Komine**.`

> Witnessing this event gave Sachi a serious case of **Post Traumatic Stress Disorder (PTSD) and Obsessive-compulsive disorder (OCD)**. She blame herself and believes that she needs to be a good girl to make up for her sins.`

http://grisaia.wikia.com/wiki/Sachi_Komine

It is shown that the other girls have or had a kind or another of mental wound.

**Yumiko Sakaki**

> His son had died, and Yumiko was being spoon fed false kindness to shape her into the next head of the company, Michiaki’s own puppet. This shook Yumiko’s foundation to the core and she was on the verge of a **mental breakdown**.

http://grisaia.wikia.com/wiki/Yumiko_Sakaki

**Amane Suou**

> The incident leaves Amane with a **strong case of survivor's guilt**, which is only compounded by media speculation that she survived by engaging in cannibalism. Years later, when Yuuji arrives at Mihama, she recognizes him as Kazuki's brother, and attempts to "atone for her crimes" by helping him in any way she can.

http://grisaia.wikia.com/wiki/Amane_Suou

**Michiru Matsushima**

> After that incident, Michiru gets sent to a **mental ward** and there she is prescribed a medication to suppress the "other Michiru." A little while later she got released from the **mental hospital** and enrolls in to Mihama academy as the third student after its establishment.

http://grisaia.wikia.com/wiki/Michiru_Matsushima

**Makina Irisu**

> Makina used to be the successor of Irisu family but her inheritance was transferred to her younger sister, Sarina Irisu , after she suffered a **mental shock** in an incident.

http://grisaia.wikia.com/wiki/Makina_Irisu

As for **Chizuru Tachibana** , I didn't find in the wiki or in the anime anything that would indicate the fact that she would have some kind of mental scar.